# Target API level requirement from late 2018

Tags: android, google-play, updates

I don't know if this is a correct place where ask the following:

I have read on the google play developer console that :

> In the second half of 2018, Play will require that new apps and app
>   updates target a recent Android API level. This will be required for
>   new apps in August 2018, and for updates to existing apps in November
>   2018. This is to ensure apps are built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance

and

> Google Play will require that new apps target at least Android 8.0
>   (API level 26) from August 1, 2018, and that app updates target
>   Android 8.0 from November 1, 2018.

What does this mean? Does this mean that I will not be able to develop applications compatible with versions smaller than 8.0?

If so, how can bug fixings / new features be introduced within existing apps with versions other than 8.0?

This would result in a "death" of all devices with version other than 8.0 ... Or is Google thinking about releasing android oreo for all devices on the market?

*************** EDIT ***************

The doubt arises from this message on my account of google developer console:

[image]

The translation is :

Starting from August 2018, the new apps must **minimum target** Android 8.0. 
Starting in November 2018, app updates must target version 8.0

The minumum target is :

> An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the
>   application to run.The Android system will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the value specified in this attribute.

Bad interpretation of the message ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> What does this mean?

What it means is, you should ensure you have set `targetSdkVersion` to `26` in your `build.gradle` and your application is compatible with Android O behavior changes.

> Does this mean that I will not be able to develop  application compatible with versions smaller than 8.0?

You can set `minSdkVersion` lower than 8.0.

> This would result in a "death" of all devices with version other than
>   8.0 ... Or is Google thinking about releasing android oreo for all devices on the market?

The [distribution rate](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/#platform) for Android O is still around 6%, which means older versions still constitute around 94%. They cannot implement drastic changes for this reason. Older OS version will be still supported until the adaptation for Android O changes drastically. It could be challenging because it involves adaptation from huge number of manufacturers.

If you are uploading your app as your first release, then you must ensure you are compatible with Android O.

For updates to existing app, the deadline is November.

onsole, Android Studio, and Firebase. Start survey
Meet Google Play's target API level requirement

> Bad interpretation of the message ?

Actual statement in English [from site is](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk):

> Google Play will require that new apps target **at least** Android 8.0
>   (API level 26) from August 1, 2018, and that app updates target
>   Android 8.0 from November 1, 2018.

Comment: Can I say that the translation of the Italian version is ambiguous?

Comment: @Max yeah. A bit, especially `must minimum target Android 8.0`

Comment: @Sagar, The [Google Announcement](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk#check_and_update_your_sdks_and_libraries) also says, "Make sure that your third-party SDK dependencies support API 26". Is anyone aware of how the Google Play Store could validate that? AFAIK, the targetSdkVersion value of your app is the only version that appears in the compiled apk. When it comes to libraries, do they use the targetSdkVersion your app specifies? I'm really curious if other developers are updating their libs too?

Comment: @blinkmacalahan Thanks for your comment.`Is anyone aware of how the Google Play Store could validate that?`At present, it doesn't seem so. As per my interpretation, it just says, please ensure this is the case to avoid issues. `AFAIK, the targetSdkVersion value of your app is the only version that appears in the compiled apk.` Yes. You can check the merged manifest.xml to confirm

Comment: So suppose if i am using BarcodeScanner library which is support targetSDK 25, do i have to update the library aswell?

Answer (score 9):

> You should first understand the difference between *TARGET API* and *MINIMUM
>   API* Levels.

As a reminder, target API level is different from minimum API level. As the name implies, minimum API level is used to declare the lowest version of Android an app supports. The target API level is technically defined as the version of the operating system an app was tested to work with; but in more practical terms, it's used to define a set of behaviors an app expects from the operating system.

Please follow this link to view the complete source of this information: 
https://www.androidpolice.com/2017/12/19/play-store-require-new-updated-apps-target-recent-api-levels-distribute-native-apps-64-bit-support/

Answer (score 2):

Just update your **compileSdkVersion** and **targetSdkVersion** to 26 (or better to 28).
And read about *minimum api version* and *target api version*. It`s important to understand.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element

Answer (score 0):

> What does this mean?

its means that you need to set target sdk Android 8.0 (26 API)

> Does this mean that I will not be able to develop applications compatible with versions smaller than 8.0?

**No** it means that  the end November your app must compatible with Android O (26 API)

> This would result in a "death" of all devices with version other than 8.0

**NO**

> how can bug fixings / new features be introduced within existing apps with versions other than 8.0?

it will support all features introduced within existing apps with versions other than 8.0

> is Google thinking about releasing android oreo for all devices on the market?

Nobody knows the future